# Android XML Layout - 4 ImageViews on one screen

Tags: xml, android, layout

I thought I have understood the XML layout of Android, but it seems that I haven't.
I want to have four ImageViews on one screen, to view four images at the same time.

It should look like this, where A to D represents the image views:

```
DDDAAA
DDDAAA
BBBCCC
BBBCCC
```

How can I do that? I tried it this way, but it's not working. The Eclipse Editor seems not to be very good for this either. Is there a better one to create those layouts ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableRow>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" ></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView04" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
  </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about :

- a `LinearLayout`, with `vertical` orientation, that would contain everything
- and, then, a first `LinearLayout`, with `horizontal` orientation

  - that would contain D and A,
- and the same kind of `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation, a second time, for B and C

And using

- `android:layout_weight`
- and `android:gravity="center"`

so each Layout takes enough place and is centered ?

A bit like this, I'd say :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DashboardNewPost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/new_post"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DashboardPostsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/posts_list"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DashboardCommentsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/comments_list"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DashboardBlogParameters"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_params"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I suppose *(not tried)* that you could even remove the `LinearLayout` that's just arround each `ImageView`, adding the attributes it has to the `ImageView`s instead...

*(In the application I took this from, I had to add those `LinearLayout` because there are more than only those images)*

Comment: Cool ! That was exactly, what I searched for. I haven't known the vertical and horizontal option of LinearLayout as I used the editor, which is hard to use in my opinion. Thank very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have TableRows in a RelativeLayout.  It might help you to read through the introductory layout [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html).  It explains the different layout types and their usages.

For your case, you should be able to change RelativeLayout to TableLayout.

Also, when asking layout questions its helpful if you explain the behavior you are seeing with your attempt, rather than just saying it doesn't work.